# A Possible characterization of F.D or AF commutative $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

By F.D or  AF  $C^{*}$ algebra,we mean finite  dimensional or  approximately finite  dimensional $C^{*}$  algebra.

Let $A$ be  a unital  commutative  $C^{*}$ algebra with the  property that for every unital $C^{*}$  subalgebra $B\subset A$, $Spec(B)$ is  embeddable in $Spec(A)$.

What can be said  about $A$? Is  $A$ F.D  or  at least $AF$? does every $AF$  algebra satisfy  the above property?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what are the motivation for the formulaton in terms of $C^*$ algebras, but you are essentially asking for hausdorff compact/locally compact spaces such all their compact/locally compact quotients can be embeded into them.

Finite topological space do have this property. But the [Hilbert cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube) also have this property (and the corresponding $C^*$-algebra really don't look approximately finite dimensional ).

**Edit:** I realize there is a small gap in the previous argument: If you consider non unital $C^*$-algebras of $C(X)$ then they do not correspond to quotients of $X$, but to proper quotients of an open subspace of $X$, so the topological interpretation I gave does not work. This being said, the Hilbert cube is still a valid counter exemple: any separated quotient of an open subspace is metrizable and separable and hence can be embedded in the Hilbert cube.

Comment: Thanks  for  the  very interesting  answer. Some  more  question: By  quotient, do you  mean  an arbitrary  quotient  by an  equivalent relation or  a  particular  collapsing $X/A$?  Moreover, what do you mean  by "separated" quotient?  The  last question what  about $X$=  the  cantor  set or  arbitrary  totally  disconnected  compact metric  space? I  mean is  every AF  algebra  satisfies in the statment under my  question?

Comment: By quotient I mean by an aribitrary equivalence relation, but such that the quotient is separated (i.e. by a closed equivalence relation). That is what a unital subalgebra of C(X) is: a compact topological space endowed with a surjection from X. By compactness this is automatically a quotient map. For your other question, I don't know.